# gem install fastlane -> no such name

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems, fastlane

I am running OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4.

I am using the command `sudo gem install fastlane` (also tried without sudo).

I am getting this message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'fastlane' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I understand this is not a fastlane specific error. It sounds like DNS lookup failure but I do not know where to begin to solve it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:
http://jacob.stanley.io/2010/10/27/sudo-gem-install-behind-a-proxy/

I needed to route "gem" through a proxy using export

```
export http_proxy=http://my.proxy.com:80
export https_proxy=https://my.proxy.com:80
```

I skipped the part about adding this line to `visudo` (but I will post it for completeness)

```
Defaults        env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

Finally my original command worked

```
sudo gem install fastlane --verbose
```